# ldap_add: Insufficient access (50)

Tags: openldap, centos7

I am trying to add the below entry using the command below:

```
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f server5_ldap.ldif
```

The contents of server5_ldap.ldif is provided below:

```
# Entry 31: cn=default,ou=pwpolicies,dc=example,dc=com
dn: cn=default,ou=pwpolicies,dc=example,dc=com
cn: default
objectclass: device
objectclass: top
objectclass: pwdPolicy
objectclass: pwdPolicyChecker
pwdallowuserchange: TRUE
pwdattribute: userPassword
pwdcheckquality: 2
pwdexpirewarning: 604800
pwdfailurecountinterval: 3600
pwdgraceauthnlimit: 0
pwdinhistory: 5
pwdlockout: TRUE
pwdlockoutduration: 900
pwdmaxage: 0
pwdmaxfailure: 5
pwdminage: 0
pwdminlength: 8
pwdmustchange: FALSE
pwdsafemodify: FALSE
```

I am getting the error:

```
ldap_add: Insufficient access (50)
    additional info: no write access to parent
```

My permissions.ldif is as given below:

```
#OlcAccess
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0} to attrs=userPassword by self write by anonymous auth by dn.exact="cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com" manage by dn.exact="cn=admin,cn=config" manage by dn.exact="cn=ConnectedSyncAdmin,ou=customers,dc=example,dc=com" write by * none
olcAccess: {1} to attrs=uid by self write by anonymous auth by dn.exact="cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com" manage  by dn.exact="cn=admin,cn=config" manage by dn.exact="cn=ConnectedSyncAdmin,ou=customers,dc=example,dc=com" write by * none
olcAccess: {2} to attrs=objectClass by self write by anonymous auth by dn.exact="cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com" manage by dn.exact="cn=admin,cn=config" manage by dn.exact="cn=ConnectedSyncAdmin,ou=customers,dc=example,dc=com" write by * none
olcAccess: {3} to attrs=cn by self write by anonymous auth by dn.exact="cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com" manage by dn.exact="cn=admin,cn=config" manage by dn.exact="cn=ConnectedSyncAdmin,ou=customers,dc=example,dc=com" write by * none
olcAccess: {4} to attrs=sn by self write by anonymous auth by dn.exact="cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com" manage by dn.exact="cn=admin,cn=config" manage by dn.exact="cn=ConnectedSyncAdmin,ou=customers,dc=example,dc=com" write by * none
olcAccess: {5} to * by self write by dn.exact="cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com" manage by dn.exact="cn=admin,cn=config" manage by dn.exact="cn=ConnectedSyncAdmin,ou=customers,dc=example,dc=com" write by users read by anonymous none
olcAccess: {6} to attrs=userPassword by self write by anonymous auth by dn.exact="cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com" manage by dn.exact="cn=admin,cn=config" manage by dn.exact="cn=pwpolicies,ou=PPS,dc=example,dc=com" write by * none
```

I am new to ldap, and I am blocked with this issue Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to supply a user DN and password that has write access to the DIT. At present you're trying to do it anonymously. No sanely configured DIT would allow that.

Comment: Ok thank you, so I tried with this  ldapadd -x -D cn=Manager,dc=mydomain,dc=com -w Password1 -f new.ldif but I get ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1) error. Could you kindly suggest how I could get this resolved?

Comment: Your access control list seems to be a bit buggy. The last rule (6) will never match, because it is shadowed by the first rule (0). Normally you can have only one rule per target. If you want to specify two rules, you have to use the [control field break](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapd.access&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.4-Release#THE_%26lt%3bCONTROL%26gt%3b_FIELD).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Unix domain socket authentication (`-Y EXTERNAL`), then you have to give `root` the `manage` permission to the database.  The `dn` for `root` authenticating via Unix domain sockets is:

```
gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
```

On Redhat and CentOS only the configuration and the monitor back-ends have root permission.

```
# ldapsearch -Y EXTERNAL -Q -H ldapi:/// -LLL -o ldif-wrap=no -b cn=config '(objectClass=olcDatabaseConfig)' olcAccess 
dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config

dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" manage by * none

dn: olcDatabase={1}monitor,cn=config
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" read by * none

dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
```

If you want to manage database 2 in the same way you manage the configuration, you have to add the same `olcAccess` rule to database 2 as it is defined for database 0, the configuration back-end.

```
to * by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" manage
```